# Cannot find or load main class issue

Tags: java

All of my files are in the same folder, and they all have `package csit254project03simulationusingqueues21;` at the top of them.

I try compiling and running the program but it says it can't find the main function.

```
javac *.java
java csit254project03simulationusingqueues21.Example
Error: Could not find or load main class csit254project03simulationusingqueues21.Example
```

`Example.java` is the file that has the `main` function in it.

```
package csit254project03simulationusingqueues21;

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        runMe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: There's a lot of files. Do you just need `Example`?

Comment: Yes - I don't think this could be caused by other classes.

Comment: I'm assuming that you accidentally reversed java and javac.

Comment: @NomadMaker Yes let me change that

Comment: This is some what speculative, does `java -cp .. csit254project03simulationusingqueues21.Example` work?

Comment: right click on the class which you want to run and select run as and then click java application

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer I am using Linux Mint and that option doesn't show up

Comment: I think you are in the wrong directory.  When you run `java csit254project03simulationusingqueues21.Example`, you need to be in a directory that has a subdirectory called `csit254project03simulationusingqueues21`.  In that directory, you should see `Example.class`.  If you don't ... then `java` or `java -cp .` won't find the class.

Comment: which  ide are you using?

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer - Clearly the OP is using the command line.

Comment: @StephenC That was the issue. Thanks!